# How to Write Cos Inverse

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, trigonometry

How would I make cos inverse.

```cs
float A = (float)Math.Cos((DeltaY * DeltaY + Hyp * Hyp - DeltaX * DeltaX) / (2 * Hyp * DeltaY));
```

This is my code. I need to use the cosine law for angle so I need cos inverse.

Answer (score 1):

To use cos inverse in C# try using `Math.Acos()` method, It returns the angle whose cosine is the specified number.